# Pass & as part of value in url in javascript

Tags: php

I have one URL like:

```
<ul>
<?php
$sql = "select * from product";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
?>
   <li> <a href="test.php?id=<?php $row['name']?>"><?php $row['name']?></a></li>
<?php
}
?>
</ul>
```

when here $row['name'] has "Tea & Coffee" then PHP Side:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Value of `$id` is **"Tea"** but I need whole string as **"Tea & Coffee"**.

Comment: Isn't stackoverflow on the web? Am I missing something ;-)

Comment: urlencoding? I don't understand why you involve javascript? Please explain.

Comment: Javascript has methods [`encodeURI()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) and [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) that can be used to generate a URL safe string. PHP also has an equivalent function [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php).

Comment: @Aiias - yes, I know that. but it seems pointless to use javascript when you don't have to. Maybe there are a reason for using javascript but that isn't clear enough in the question.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld - The way the question is phrased, it does not imply `javascript` is involved. It should probably have the [tag:javascript] tag removed.

Comment: @Aiias - "Pass & as part of value in url in javascript" is the actual question....

Answer (score 1):

You need to URL encode the spaces and the ampersand.

Try this:

```
test.php?id=tea+%26+coffee
```

You can test out URL encoding here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp.

> URL Encoding URLs can only be sent over the Internet using the ASCII
>   character-set.
>
> Since URLs often contain characters outside the ASCII set, the URL has
>   to be converted into a valid ASCII format.
>
> URL encoding replaces unsafe ASCII characters with a "%" followed by
>   two hexadecimal digits. URLs cannot contain spaces. URL encoding
>   normally replaces a space with a + sign.

Quoted From http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Read more about why URL encoding a query string is necessary here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#URL_encoding .

Comment: @zzzzBov - Quoted from w3fools as the explanation on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) was not as clear.

Comment: [Wikipedia's a much better reference for a case such as this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#URL_encoding). MDN is focused on the functionality of the function, OP needs more domain knowledge of how query-strings actually work.

Comment: @zzzzBov - Thanks for the answering best practice. I've added an additional resource to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

URL encode the &-sign and the spaces

[Here for instance](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/)